# How to ingore TIMEOUT error in While loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am downloading historic data from NSE site and running below code. It is give **TIMEOUT** error for public holidays as data in not available for those days. How can I ignore this error and let the loop continue for next date.

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
from jugaad_data.nse import bhavcopy_fo_save
i=0
while i<2610:
    Date = (datetime.today() - BDay(i)).date()
    bhavcopy_fo_save(Date, r"C:\Users\Mohit\ALGO_TRADING\bhavcopy")
    i=i+1
```

I have pasted error screenshot as below-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjKe9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8YdI.png)

Thanks,
Mohit

Comment: You need to use `try` and `except`, catching `ConnectionError`

Comment: '
except ConnectionError:
        pass
`
Like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to wrap the code that might throw the exception in a try-except block.

So for instance:

```
try: 
    bhavcopy_fo_save(Date, r"C:\Users\Mohit\ALGO_TRADING\bhavcopy")
catch TimeoutError as e:
    pass
```

Instead of pass you could print the error or something else that acknowledges that the error occured, but it will no longer stop the program.